# What is the optional `BUFFER` argument to `describe-symbol` for?

Tags: help

I'm trying to add additional contextual help information to `describe-function`, `describe-variable` etc, and I notice that `describe-symbol` has the option to take a buffer as a parameter.

When I try `(describe-symbol 'variable (get-buffer-create "buffer name"))` the usual help buffers are used.

> describe-symbol is an autoloaded interactive compiled Lisp function in
> ‘help-fns.el’.
>
> It is bound to C-h o,  o,  o.
>
> (describe-symbol SYMBOL &optional BUFFER FRAME)
>
> Probably introduced at or before Emacs version 25.1.
>
> Display the full documentation of SYMBOL. Will show the info of SYMBOL
> as a function, variable, and/or face. Optional arguments BUFFER and
> FRAME specify for which buffer and frame to show the information about
> SYMBOL; they default to the current buffer and the selected frame,
> respectively.

Is that a bug in the `describe-symbol` implementation?

I'm on Emacs 27.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've misread the docs.  Those arguments have no bearing on which help buffer is used.

"**for** which buffer and frame" rather than "**in** which buffer and frame".

Think buffer-local variables.

Comment: What is the significance of the `for which buffer and frame` distinction? Are there some special buffers that the info is displayed in?

Comment: `for which buffer and frame` means **about** which buffer and frame. As @phils said in his answer, `BUFFER` here is about describing the use of the `SYMBOL` in the given `BUFFER`.